# How can I solve RuntimeError that closed the session?

Tags: tensorflow, chatbot

I am building a chatbot using TensorFlow and Python, and I am encountering a RuntimeError that says "Attempted to use a closed Session." How can I resolve this issue?

Here's what my chatbot is supposed to do: it reads in data from a [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) file containing a list of intents, and then trains a neural network model using [TFLearn](http://tflearn.org/). The model is then used to predict the intent of user input and respond with an appropriate message.

Here's the code I'm using:

```python
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
from nltk.stem.lancaster import LancasterStemmer
stemmer = LancasterStemmer()
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops

import numpy
import tensorflow as tf
import tflearn
import random
import json
import pickle

from time import sleep

with open("intents.json") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

try:
    with open("data.pickle", "rb") as f:
        words, labels, training, output = pickle.load(f)
except:
    words = []
    labels = []
    docs_x = []
    docs_y = []
    for intent in data ["intents"]:
        for pattern in intent["patterns"]:
            wrds = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
            words.extend(wrds)
            docs_x.append(wrds)
            docs_y.append(intent["tag"])

        if intent["tag"] not in labels:
            labels.append(intent["tag"])

    words = [stemmer.stem(w.lower()) for w in words if w != "?"]
    words = sorted(list(set(words)))

    labels = sorted(labels)

    training = []
    output = []

    out_empty = [0 for _ in range(len(labels))]

    for x, doc in enumerate(docs_x):
        bag = []

        wrds = [stemmer.stem(w) for w in doc]

        for w in words:
            if w in wrds:
                bag.append(1)
            else:
                bag.append(0)


        output_row = out_empty[:]
        output_row[labels.index(docs_y[x])] = 1

        training.append(bag)
        output.append(output_row)


    training = numpy.array(training)
    output = numpy.array(output)

    with open("data.pickle", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump((words, labels, training, output), f)

ops.reset_default_graph()

net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, len(training[0])])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, len(output[0]), activation = "softmax")
net = tflearn.regression(net)

model = tflearn.DNN(net)

try:
    model.load("model.tflearn")
except:
    model.fit(training, output, n_epoch=1000, batch_size=8, show_metric=True)
    model.save("model.tflearn")

def bag_of_words(s, words):
    bag = [0 for _ in range(len(words))]

    s_words = nltk.word_tokenize(s)
    s_words = [stemmer.stem(word.lower()) for word in s_words]

    for se in s_words:
        for i, w in enumerate(words):
            if w == se:
                bag[i] = 1

    return numpy.array(bag)

def chat():
    print("Hi, How can i help you ?")
    while True:
        inp = input("You: ")
        if inp.lower() == "quit":
            break

        results = model.predict([bag_of_words(inp, words)])[0]
        results_index = numpy.argmax(results)
        tag = labels[results_index]
        if results[results_index] > 0.8:
            for tg in data["intents"]:
                if tg['tag'] == tag:
                    responses = tg['responses']
            sleep(3)
            Bot = random.choice(responses)
            print(Bot)
        else:
            print("I don't understand!")
chat()
```

The output error is:

```
raise RuntimeError('Attempted to use a closed Session.')
RuntimeError: Attempted to use a closed Session.
```

Answer (score 0):

While I can give you the solution as in where to correct the code so as to remove the error, I'd suggest you to use [Keras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keras) here.

**TFlearn was a wrapper over TensorFlow 1.x.**

TFlearn is **not compatible with TensorFlow 2.x**, but Keras is. There was an update with TFlearn which used tf.compat.v1 for using with TensorFlow 2.x, but that is deprecated now and the only way forward is Keras.

The same code for building a chatbot with the **intents.json** file which you are using along with the **Lancaster Stemmer** in [NLTK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_Language_Toolkit) is given [here](https://data-flair.training/blogs/python-chatbot-project/). It is written in Keras along with the latest version of TensorFlow.

**Coming to the error,**

> RuntimeError: Attempted to use a closed Session.

TFLearn uses TensorFlow 1.x which uses the **tf.session()** approach while writing the code.

Here what is happening is, TFLearn is trying to call `sess.run()` outside of the `with tf.Session()` as the `sess` scope which automatically closes the `sess` object once it goes out of scope.

Hence while calling the model, in your code, the error is coming from the **except block**:

> ```
> try:
>     model.load("model.tflearn")
> except:
>     model.fit(training, output, n_epoch=1000, batch_size=8, show_metric=True)
>     model.save("model.tflearn")
> ```

In your existing code, if you use this instead, you can resolve it.

```
model.fit(training, output, n_epoch=1000, batch_size=8, show_metric=True)
model.save("model.tflearn")
```

(Remove `try:` and `except:` and only using two last lines solves the problem.)

You can refer to the gist as given [here](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/drive/1J6x1ze1t6amWB5S6bOdLeoX4Nl0VG31b#scrollTo=l3105R5wJGIZ).